# Specify thumbnail dimensions and number of generated thumbnails in AWS Elastic Transcoder in PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Is it possible to specify the size of the thumbnails and the number of generated thumbnails when creating a job in Elastic Transcoder?

I'm using the PHP SDK of AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the job preset to set thumbnail properties. You can set the maximum width and height of the generated thumbnails in the preset. As for the number of thumbnails you can only set an interval value. So if you were to set interval to 10 it will generate a thumbnail every 10 seconds. You can create as many presets as necessary from within the Elastic Transcoder console https://console.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/home.